# Android: Scheduled Task With Exact Time & Network Connectivity

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, network-connection

Trying to implement a requirement where a:

- background task needs to be fired off at **exact** time scheduled by a user (like an alarm clock),
- with this task making a network connection and performing sync w/ server
- requirement calls for minSDK 14 and up.

I'm familiar with available API's for background task scheduling like **AlarmManager**, **JobScheduler**, **GcmNetworkManager** and the new **WorkManager** -

However all of them fall short and after Oreo API changes it seems very difficult (if not impossible) to achieve this exact requirement.

The issue is:

- **AlarmManager** can guarantee exact time scheduling / task execution - but network connectivity will likely be off at that time.
- **JobScheduler** / **GcmNetworkManager** / **WorkManager** - can fire when network is connected (during maintenance windows), but are designed for deferrable tasks and do not guarantee that the task will run at exact scheduled time.

Need suggestions on approach / strategy on how to achieve exact task scheduling with network connectivity - perhaps chaining multiple API's or using something different.

Comment: Setting alarms to fire at specified period of time in the future is possible to do ( I mean exact and repeating), I've done so far application using AlarmManager especially for Oreo and it works fine. But can you explain what do you exactly mean by displaying result to the user? How result is to be displayed? Like notification or device is to be woken up and then data is to be displayed?

Comment: @Domin thanks for reply. Displaying result isn't actually an issue (I'll remove that from question). The issue is network connectivity. Yes AlarmManager works for exact scheduling, however there is no guarantee of network connectivity. With Oreo / Dose network will be off when the alarm fires.

Comment: have you found an answer to your problem. I am facing exactly the same issue now

Comment: @White No I haven't. Please up-vote the question so it gets more attention.

Comment: i have tried using alarm manager to fire every day at 6.00 and in its receiver started jobscheduler but in some cases it doesnt worked well so I removed alarm manager and now i am using only job scheduler

Comment: @White - but that means it won't fire exactly at 6:00. What was your experience?

Comment: yeah exactly it starts alarm manager every day at 6.00 and if there is internet connection it starts job scheduler or it waits until there is internet connection and then starts it. It was exactly what I needed but alarm manager is not working perfectly on newer android versions

Comment: From my research the only reliable way to wake the device on time with internet connection is to implement Android Push Notifications, but that would require a server component.